# Determining your ancestry through the shape of your feet?

Tags: biology

This picture makes its rounds around blogs & forums recently:

[image]

Does it have any scientific backing?

Comment: I'll point out that as-presented, this only really helps with european-heritages.  There's no African, Asian, South American, etc. foot shapes.  So while there may or may not be *some* truth to this, it's by no means comprehensive.  (Still researching whether there is that grain of truth.)

Comment: Unsourced answer, based on [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/1xupe6/is_there_any_validity_to_this_image/): The names are based on the style of toes in that culture's statues.  Can't verify it, but someone might be able to use that as a jumping off point.

Comment: Shouldn't be too hard to find sources for this, but for most people, the #1 cause of the shape of your feet is the shape of your shoes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**There is no scientific backing for this classification.**

What is referenced as "Greek" is actually called [**Morton's toe**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morton's_toe) (name derived from the surgeon who described is as a foot syndrome), but it's so common that this congenital short first metatarsal bone is considered a normal variant of foot shape.

In statuary and shoe fitting it has been called Greek foot, because it was an [idealized form in Greek sculpture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyf3kq69NWs). It also persisted as an aesthetic standard through Roman and Renaissance periods:

[image]

<sub>Greek bronze statue of boxer at rest | © Joseph Uj/Flickr</sub>

**The relative length of the big and second toes varies continuously**, so [there aren't just two categories of toe length](http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/mythtoelength.html). The mechanisms that determine how Morton's toe is inherited are determined by more than one gene, or by a combination of genetics and the environment. These mechanisms haven't proven to be specific to a geographic area, [as referenced by Kaplan](http://www.omim.org/entry/189200).